# Putting an ItemContainerStyle on a Grid

Tags: winrt-xaml

Obviously ItemContainerStyle doesn't exist in a Grid, which is the problem.

My program has a ListView that displays a bunch of projects. I want to add a button to each project that gives more info, and that much I can do easily. The problem I'm encountering is the border that appears on each project, which is toggled on/off by clicking the project to show the user which are currently selected. I don't want this border to encircle my button; I want the button placed to the right of the bit with the border.

I can't put the button on a separate list or I'll get two different scroll-able lists, so it must stay within the ListView, but any border on the ListView will encircle everything in the ListView. My solution was to make a StackPanel with two Grids inside the ListView, where the first Grid has all of my old stuff and the toggle-able border and the second grid only has my button. So now I just need to move that border onto the Grid... but how?

XAML code:

```
<!-- Other code up above... -->
            <ListView x:Name="lstAvailableProjects"
                      Grid.Row="1" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Height="Auto"  
                      Width="Auto"
                      SelectionMode="Multiple"    
                      IsRightTapEnabled="True"
                      IsDoubleTapEnabled="False"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                      SelectionChanged="lstAvailableProjects_SelectionChanged" 
                      Background="Transparent"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ActiveProjectListViewStyle}"
                      BorderThickness="30,0,0,0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="250" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource projectStateColorConverter}}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName}" 
                                       Foreground="Black" 
                                       Margin="10 5 0 0"
                                       FontSize="17"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Grid.Row="0"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AssignmentRole}"
                                       Visibility="{Binding ProjectAssignmentRole, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                                       Foreground="Black" 
                                       Margin="10 3 0 5"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusText}"
                                       Foreground="Red"
                                       Margin="10 3 0 5"
                                       Grid.Row="2"
                                       FontSize="14"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid>
                                <Button>
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="../Assets/setting_icon.png" Height="40" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the grid items are wrapped You cannot make changes in xaml to achieve it other than overriding the preparecontainerforitemoverride.

A little tricky hack would be to apply transform to the button.

```
<Button.RenderTransform>
 <CompositeTransform TranslateX="100" TranslateY="100"/>
<Button.RenderTransform>
```

Comment: That does exactly what I need it to. Thank you!